# Dataframe to Nested Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Having a bit of trouble here..  I need to take a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

region = ['A','A','A','B','B','B']
sub_region = ['1','2','2','3','3','4']
state = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

pd.DataFrame({"region":region,"sub_region":sub_region,"state":state})
```

and convert into a nested dictionary with the following format:

```
[{name: "thing", children: [{name:"sub_thing",children:[{...}] }]}]
```

so a list of nested dictionaries where the key value pairs are always name:"", children:[{}], but childless children don't have children in their dict.. so the final desired output would be...

```
[{"name":"A",
    "children":[{"name":"1","children":[{"name":"a"}]},
                {"name":"2","children":[{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"}]}]
 },
 {"name":"B",
    "children":[{"name":"3","children":[{"name":"d"},{"name":"e"}]},
                {"name":"4","children":[{"name":"f"}]}]
 }
]
```

Assume a generalized framework where the number of levels can vary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do better than looping through the rows of the dataframe. That is, I don't see a way to vectorize this process. Also, if the number of levels can vary within the same dataframe, then the update function should be modified to handle `nan` entries (e.g. adding `and not np.isnan(row[1])` to `if len(row) > 1`).

That said, I believe that the following script should be satisfactory.

```
import pandas as pd

region = ['A','A','A','B','B','B']
sub_region = ['1','2','2','3','3','4']
state = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

df = pd.DataFrame({"region":region,"sub_region":sub_region,"state":state})
ls = []

def update(row,ls):
    for d in ls:
        if d['name'] == row[0]:
            break
    else:
        ls.append({'name':row[0]})
        d = ls[-1]
    if len(row) > 1:
        if not 'children' in d:
            d['children'] = []
        update(row[1:],d['children'])

for _,r in df.iterrows():
    update(r,ls)

print(ls)
```

The resulting list ls:

```
[{'name': 'A',
  'children': [{'name': '1', 'children': [{'name': 'a'}]},
   {'name': '2', 'children': [{'name': 'b'}, {'name': 'c'}]}]},
 {'name': 'B',
  'children': [{'name': '3', 'children': [{'name': 'd'}, {'name': 'e'}]},
   {'name': '4', 'children': [{'name': 'f'}]}]}]
```

Here's a version where childless children have `'children':[]` in their dict, which I find a bit more natural.

```
import pandas as pd

region = ['A','A','A','B','B','B']
sub_region = ['1','2','2','3','3','4']
state = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

df = pd.DataFrame({"region":region,"sub_region":sub_region,"state":state})
ls = []

def update(row,ls):
    if len(row) == 0:
        return
    for d in ls:
        if d['name'] == row[0]:
            break
    else:
        ls.append({'name':row[0], 'children':[]})
        d = ls[-1]
    update(row[1:],d['children'])

for _,r in df.iterrows():
    update(r,ls)

print(ls)
```

The resulting list ls:

```
[{'name': 'A',
  'children': [{'name': '1', 'children': [{'name': 'a', 'children': []}]},
   {'name': '2',
    'children': [{'name': 'b', 'children': []},
     {'name': 'c', 'children': []}]}]},
 {'name': 'B',
  'children': [{'name': '3',
    'children': [{'name': 'd', 'children': []},
     {'name': 'e', 'children': []}]},
   {'name': '4', 'children': [{'name': 'f', 'children': []}]}]}]
```

Comment: bless you!  worked like a charm.  thankfully I don't need to parse this on the fly, so vectorization is not a priority at all.

Comment: @Zach Glad to hear it! If that's everything you were looking for, I'd appreciate it if you would "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark (**✓**) underneath the vote arrows on my answer.